# Python pickle custom class object leads to Segmentation Fault

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, pickle, dlib

I am using dlib's HOG face detector. Trying to set and load the model to/from redis (localhost) by pickling/unpickling leads to a segmentation fault. Below is the code for the same.

```
from redis import Redis
from pickle import dumps, loads

redis = Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0, password='')

from dlib import get_frontal_face_detector
face_detector = get_frontal_face_detector()
redis.set('faceDetector',dumps(face_detector))
retobj = loads(redis.get('faceDetector'))
```

Leads to

```
Segmentation Fault (core dumped)
```

loads and dumps are chosen to pickle and unpickle a custom class object (dlib.HOG_detector) to the redis memory. Have also tried using the 'dill' library with no luck.

What is perplexing is the fact that this runs without any error on my local machine (OS X), however the same run on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with Python 2.7.12 results in the aforementioned.

The only other difference between the operating systems that I haven't included above is the fact that I run the code in a virtualenv on my local machine. However I believe this should not directly or indirectly cause this error.

Looking for any pointers or suggestions that would point me in the right direction. Thanks !

Edit : Per the suggestion by Davis, I tried to pickle the object using version 2 of the pickle format. Post this I run into the below mentioned error when trying to loads from the pickle module, something I am still unable to resolve.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1388, in loads
    return Unpickler(file).load()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 864, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1089, in load_newobj
    obj = cls.__new__(cls, *args)
TypeError: pybind11_object.__new__(dlib.fhog_object_detector) is not safe, use object.__new__()
```

Comment: Are the Python, redis, and pickle versions the same in your virtual env as on your Ubuntu system?

Comment: @UnoriginalNick, python versions are definitely different. Should that be actually a cause for concern ?

Comment: @UnoriginalNick, just checked by upgrading the python version on the server to 2.7.14 without any luck.

Comment: Read: http://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/classes.html. Pybind11 doesn’t support pickle version 1. You have to pickle using version 2 of the pickle format.

Comment: @DavisKing, thanks for the pointer. Pickle seems to work after I use version 2, but I am running into a separate error with not a lot of documentation to go on. Thanks nonetheless.